# Possible Memory Leak Valgrind in OSX El Capitan

Tags: c, macos, memory-leaks, valgrind

I'm getting a warning for `possibly lost: 2,064 bytes in 1 blocks` when using Valgrind on OSX Yosemite. Is there a fix to this? I installed valgrind using brew.

Below is an example of how to reproduce

```
~/cat hello.c
int main() {
    return 123;
}

~/uname -a
Darwin mac.local 15.2.0 Darwin Kernel Version 15.2.0: Fri Nov 13 19:56:56 PST 2015; root:xnu-3248.20.55~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64 i386 MacBookAir6,2 Darwin

~/clang --version
Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.2.0
Thread model: posix

~/valgrind --version
  valgrind-3.11.0

~/brew info valgrind
valgrind: stable 3.11.0 (bottled), HEAD
Dynamic analysis tools (memory, debug, profiling)
http://www.valgrind.org/
/usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/3.11.0 (328 files, 46.7M) *
  Poured from bottle
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/valgrind.rb

~/clang hello.c -o hello.o

~/valgrind --leak-check=full ./hello.o
==7972== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==7972== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==7972== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==7972== Command: ./hello.o
==7972== 
==7972== 
==7972== HEAP SUMMARY:
==7972==     in use at exit: 22,411 bytes in 187 blocks
==7972==   total heap usage: 271 allocs, 84 frees, 28,651 bytes allocated
==7972== 
==7972== 2,064 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 57 of 62
==7972==    at 0x10000817C: malloc_zone_malloc (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/3.11.0/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==7972==    by 0x1004F3EFD: _objc_copyClassNamesForImage (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==7972==    by 0x1004E7182: protocols() (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==7972==    by 0x1004E7093: readClass(objc_class*, bool, bool) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==7972==    by 0x1004E4C13: gc_init (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==7972==    by 0x1004EC24E: objc_initializeClassPair_internal(objc_class*, char const*, objc_class*, objc_class*) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==7972==    by 0x1004F9132: layout_string_create (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==7972==    by 0x1004E783C: realizeClass(objc_class*) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==7972==    by 0x1004E7300: copySwiftV1MangledName(char const*, bool) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==7972==    by 0x1004E72E9: copySwiftV1MangledName(char const*, bool) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==7972==    by 0x1004E72E9: copySwiftV1MangledName(char const*, bool) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==7972==    by 0x1004E72E9: copySwiftV1MangledName(char const*, bool) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==7972== 
==7972== LEAK SUMMARY:
==7972==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7972==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7972==      possibly lost: 2,064 bytes in 1 blocks
==7972==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7972==         suppressed: 20,347 bytes in 186 blocks
==7972== 
==7972== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==7972== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 17 from 17)
```

Comment: If you wouldn't mind either marking my answer correct or posting your solution if it was different, I'd appreciate it :)

Comment: Tbh I haven't touched Valgrind or c for months so I don't have an informed opinion about what's correct.  What's SO protocol in this situation?

Comment: Not sure. I guess if you're still figuring out how to resolve your issue or if you plan to try resolving some time in the future, then leave it until you find that someone's answer was helpful or just post your own answer. If you just kind of abandoned the problem altogether and don't plan to come back to it, then I figure you might as well choose an answer to close it out. You can always change the answer later if a better one comes out

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Valgrind is mostly a tool for Linux, and is less supported for OSX. This means that Valgrind will generate a lot of false positives on OSX. If you want to suppress those possibly lost leaks, then add the `--gen-suppressions=all` (or `--gen-suppressions=yes` if you want to pick and choose reported leaks one by one) option to your `valgrind` call. What this will do is print off a chunk of text for each reported memory leak that will look something like this:

```
{
   <insert_a_suppression_name_here>
   Memcheck:Leak
   match-leak-kinds: indirect
   fun:malloc
   fun:__Balloc_D2A
   fun:__rv_alloc_D2A
   fun:__dtoa
   fun:__vfprintf
   fun:__v2printf
   fun:vfprintf_l
   fun:printf
   fun:main
}
```

Copy and paste that, brackets and all, to a file  called something like `/Users/username/leak1.supp`. Feel free to change the `<...>` to an actual name for your suppression. Then when you call `valgrind`, if you add a `--suppressions=/Users/<username>/leak1.supp` option, that memory leak report will be suppressed. To make this easier, you can just put stuff in a `~/.valgrindrc` file. This file could look something like

```
--tool=memcheck
--leak-check=full
--show-reachable=yes
--suppressions=/Users/benlindsay/leak1.supp
--suppressions=/Users/benlindsay/leak2.supp
```

Or if you can just test your code on a Linux machine instead, you won't have to worry about all this ;)

--EDIT--

I got a lot of my info from [this other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12452541/2680824)

Comment: How do you know that it's a false positive?

Comment: In general I don't know how you'd tell if you're seeing a false positive or not, but in your specific case, you're not allocating any memory, so it's pretty reasonable to assume that you aren't leaking any memory.

Comment: just looked at the output again and I see swift stuff. Weird!?

Comment: Yeah, I guess some of the false positives in Mac OSX have to do with the bootstrapped C libraries (see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8657357/2680824) to another post), which might explain that...